# ¿Cómo sobrecargar el operador de inserción << en C++?

Tags: c++, operador, sobrecarga

Buen día, estoy tratando de sobrecargar el operador << en una plantilla. Lo he probado con los tipos int, double, etc. y funciona bien, pero con strings falla.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> inline vector<T> &operator<<(vector<T> &v, const T &val){
    v.push_back(val);
    return v;
}

int main(){
    vector<string> strs;
    strs << "w1" << "w2" << "w3" << "w4";

    vector<string>::iterator i;
    for(i = strs.begin(); i < strs.end(); i++)
        cout << *i << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Este es el error que pone:

```
main.cpp:14: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >' and 'const char [3]')

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:14:10: error: no match for 'operator<<'
(operand types are 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >' and 'const char [3]')
   14 |     strs << "wi" << "w2" << "w3" << "w4";
      |     ~~~~ ^~ ~~~~
      |     |       |
      |     |       const char [3]
      |     std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >

note: candidate: 'template<class T> std::vector<T>& operator<<(std::vector<T>&, const T&)'
    7 | template<typename T> inline vector<T> &operator<<(vector<T> &v, const T &val){
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:7:40: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:14:13: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter 'const T' ('std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' and 'char [3]')
   14 |     strs << "wi" << "w2" << "w3" << "w4";
      |             ^~~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El operador está correctamente sobrecargado. Lo que sucede es que los literales de cadenas son de tipo `const char *` o `const char[]` como te indica el compilador.

Puedes crear strings temporales con el propósito de satisfacer la sobrecarga:

```
strs << string("w1") << string("w2")<< string("w3") << string("w4");
```

O usar un [literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) de la librería string, agregando una **s** luego de cerrar las comillas:

```
strs << "w1"s << "w2"s << "w3"s << "w4"s;
```